# Cannot convert from wstring with Boost Format()

Tags: c++, string, boost, wstring

I have an exception class defined as follows:

```
class DeviceOpenException : public std::runtime_error {
public:
    DeviceOpenException(const std::string& message)
        : std::runtime_error("Device Open Exception: " + message) { };
};
```

And I am throwing the exception as follows:

```
throw DeviceOpenException(boost::str(boost::format("Cannot Open HID Device [Vendor ID = %1%] [Product ID = %2%] [Serial Number = %3%]") % vendorID %productID % serialNumber));
```

Where the parameters to the formater are as follows:

```
(unsigned short vendorID, unsigned short productID, std::wstring serialNumber)
```

However, this results in the following compilation error:

```
error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::wstring' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Is it me, or does the Boost formatter not work on `wstring` types?

Answer (score 3):

Use `boost::wformat` for wide strings.  See the documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/format/doc/format.html).

Note the typedef:

`typedef basic_format<wchar_t > wformat;`